# Create cloudwatch alarm for sns metric "NumberOfMessagesPublished" with boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to create a cloudwatch alarm using sns metrics, using "NumberOfMessagesPublished" metric.

For instance, I want to create an alarm for a topic with name "cloudwatch" for when the "NumberOfMessagesPublished" is >= 10 I want to send a notification for a specific topicArn.

Do you know how can I do this? Im looking for information about cloudwatch using sns metrics but I just find information about cloudwatch using ec2 metrics.

Comment: Have you tried using the boto module all the same? I know it's within the EC2 package, but that might simply reflect the most common use case. It's pretty generic looking -- I wouldn't be surprised if you can use it to monitor SNS.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Im trying to adapt the ec2 documentation to SNS, but for example If I replace "import boto.ec2.cloudwatch" to "import boto.sns.cloudwatch" I get an import error "No module named cloudwatch".

Comment: No, certainly, there's no module named `boto.sns.cloudwatch`. I was suggesting that you try and create a `boto.ec2.cloudwatch.alarm` (http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/cloudwatch.html#module-boto.ec2.cloudwatch.alarm) for your SNS resource by filling in the relevant fields.

Comment: Thanks, do you know what is the parameter to specify which topic we want that cloudwatch controls? In create_alarm we have alarm_actions=[topicArnToSend]) where we use a topicArn to send the alarm notification. But what is the parameter to specify which topic we want that cloud watch controls?